# bubba oscillator

Tags: oscillator, proteus

i am trying to make a sine wave generator. the Bubba oscillator circuit given below should produce 53 Hz. according to the text book " Op-AMP for every one", the circuit should have gain = 4, and the phase shift of 180 degrees. the values of capacitors and resistors are selected to produce 53Hz signal. everything in the circuit looks just fine to me. but when I simulate it on proteus, it has no output. what is wrong with the circuit. plus the proteus is giving some errors; pin 'V+" not modelled .  screen-shot image below.
this could be a simulator error, but what is the solution?
In the circuit, 
VCC= +12volt, VEE= -12volt.
Rf= 10k, Rg= 2.5k, 
R= 9.1k
C= 0.33uF

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't take something called a *bubba* oscilator in a book called *Op-amp for every one* too seriously.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, the bubba oscillator is just a phase shift oscillator.. here..http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sloa087/sloa087.pdf  (Opamps for everyone is from TI.)

Comment: TI calls it a "Bubba" oscillator:  https://www.ti.com/sc/docs/apps/msp/journal/aug2000/aug_07.pdf    TI is has good enough "street cred" for me!  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Oscillators like this might need a little help from noise to kick start them into operation. Noise may not be modelled into your op-amp simulation so this is likely to be a possible problem. The next problem is that you might need slightly more gain than 4 - try increasing the 10k feedback resistor on U1A to 20k.

Comment: I got your point dear, the problem could have been the absence of noise in simulation. I tried again by increasing 10k to 20k, but the result is the same. with same errors. I think I should remove the proteus simulator error first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's going to work with single sided power supply.. try a split rail.
As Andy says it's sometimes hard to get oscillators to start in simulations.  I've bump started them by sending a one time pulse into them.

Comment: it is powered with +12v and -12v. and referenced to ground (zero volt).

Comment: @MehboobAlam, OK then turn up the gain...

Comment: can I change the model for 3403 op amp i.c in proteus , or update ?

Comment: @MehboobAlam, forget my answer it looks like this will work form a single supply just fine.